# How do I use scrapy.Request right way

Tags: python, scrapy

Im trying to make my crawler crawl the next page so I wrote this function:

```
    def requestURL(self, hrefPath):
        print(hrefPath)
        url =  "http://www.presseportal.de/" + hrefPath
        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)
```

Its not even printing the variable `hrefPath` so I suspect the function isnt called, although im pretty sure I called it right like this:
`self.requestURL(hrefPath)`

Im very new to scrapy so Im very sorry if this question seems stupid

Comment: Can you post the entire class that you defined as your spider?

Comment: where do you call `requestURL()` ?

Comment: at the end of the parse function

Comment: its too long sal, but this is how I extracted my href path: ´hrefPath = str(response.xpath("/html/body/main/div[%s]/div[%s]/div[%s]/article/div[2]/a/@href"%(outerDivs, columns, rows)).extract())´ and it works fine, the function just doesnt get called

Comment: Reason for asking the full class (or most of it) was to understand if there are important missing or misplaced pieces. Scrapy is a framework, and it expects certain things to be done in a certain way. For example, do you have the "start_requests" defined? Because that's the place where the "next" url is getting computed, and things like that.

Comment: `class AlinocrawlerSpider(scrapy.Spider):
 name = "alinocrawler"
 allowed_domains = ["http://www.presseportal.de/blaulicht/d/polizei"]
 start_urls = (
  'http://www.presseportal.de/blaulicht/suche.htx?q=Raub',
  'http://www.presseportal.de/blaulicht/suche.htx?q=Diebstahl',
  'http://www.presseportal.de/blaulicht/suche.htx?q=Einbruch',` Is this what you mean? But shoudnt the function requestURL at least print hrefPath? because this is just a normal variable and has nothing to do with scrapy.

Comment: Yes, it probably should. This is beyond my knowledge of scrapy though. When sharing code snippets, you can also use https://eval.in or similar services, which is great to share more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out:
Instead of writing

`yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)`

write return

`yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)`

in the function and when you call the function in the parse function write: `yield requestURL(hrefPath)`